# Which jdbc driver version should I use to Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have database Oracle 19.12 and JDK 8. Which driver version do I need to use? I found https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 , but I don't understand, version in this case is just the artifact version (and I can use 21.7.x) or it's the database version (and I need to use 19.12.x)

Comment: The version in the maven repository are just the artifact versions. You will have to verify which versions are compatible with your sepcific db: [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

19c is a long term release. So, it is better to stick to 19c as given on the [JDBC download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html). Also, with JDK8, you must use ojdbc8.jar. Please check the JDK version supported column for each version.